# Openmaptiles cannot open /import/qeofabrik.yaml

Tags: docker, openstreetmap, mbtiles, openmaptiles

I'm struggling with generating my on .mbtiles using openmaptiles. Running the quickstart https://openmaptiles.org/docs/generate/generate-openmaptiles/
fails with:

**FATAL[0054] can't write file error=open /import/geofabrik.yml: permission denied 
make: [download-geofabrik] Error 1**

These are my files permissions:

[image]

The git is cloned into the user home on lmu and the user lmu is used to run ./quickstart.

My OS and Docker versions based on the quickstart.log:

: Area             : albania 
: Git version      : 036a96fb4035b2a94c91ee156825f0da5ea89b6c 
: Started          : 2020-03-03T07:14+0000 
: Your bash version: 4.2.46(2)-release 
: Your OS          : linux-gnu -- [Centos 7] 
Docker version 1.13.1, build b2f74b2/1.13.1 
docker-compose version 1.18.0, build 8dd22a9

Do you guys have any idea what might me the issue here ?

Thank you in advance !

Comment: can you delete the file `./data/geofabrik.yml` and try again?

Comment: Hi Mihai, there is no use file, the ./data is empty

Comment: Then delete the whole folder. It will be created anyway

Comment: this still gives the same error :(